# An unfortunate question!

Tags: support

I am sorry for creating trouble with [my first question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/19581/on-the-birth-of-latin-language?noredirect=1#comment41452_19581) on Latin SE; probably the question would be more suited for Linguistics SE in which case mods could easily move it to the  appropriate site.
The essence of my query was a comparison of the Latin language with the Indo-European languages from which the former derive. My assumption is that Latin is more sophisticated in all its aspects compared to its former languages, which, I understand is not a totally correct premise but given my limited knowledge in PIE I could only ask more knowledgeable users.
In any case, thanks for your help.

Comment: Yeah you didn't create any trouble at all! Immo, you triggered interesting discussions, so well done.

Comment: I really like the question, actually! I've wondered similar things myself.

Comment: We ask questions because we don't know the answers. Sometimes the answer is that a premise was wrong. You couldn't have known without asking, but you did know after getting an answer, so all's well.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the question has currently been voted up to +10 with no downvotes, so I don't think you've been creating trouble!

Linguistics is a good place to ask questions about PIE, but if they pertain to Latin specifically (like "did the noun cases in Latin already exist in PIE or did they develop later"), there are a bunch of historical linguists here too. The overlap between people interested in ancient languages and people interested in proto-languages is quite significant.